# What do I have to do to comply with encryption compliance with app that encrypts chat messages?

Tags: flutter, encryption

I am developing a flutter app which encrypts and decripts chat messages held on a server.
I use the following library: https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt
My code is as follows:
`

```
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as encrypt;

class Environment {
  static const ekey = String.fromEnvironment('ENCRYPT_KEY');
  static const ivkey = String.fromEnvironment('IV_KEY');
}

final key = encrypt.Key.fromBase64(Environment.ekey);
final iv = encrypt.IV.fromBase64(Environment.ivkey);


final encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.AES(key));

String Encrypt(input) {
  final encryptedText = encrypter.encrypt(input, iv: iv);
  return encryptedText.base64;
}
String Decrypt(input){
  final fb64 = encrypt.Encrypted.fromBase64(input);
  final decryptedText = encrypter.decrypt(fb64, iv: iv);
  return decryptedText;
}
```

The app will be held on apple and google stores, and I am planning to allow users in countries outside the US to download the app.

I have looked online but this seems like a minefield.

I would just like to know what I need to do to not fall foul of the law.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seeks legal advice.

Comment: If you haven't done so, check the encrypt package's github page -- there's an open issue on this very topic.  If you've already resolved it, let me know what you did.  Seems like excluding the app from French distribution is the easiest solution, but assumes that "encrypt" only uses "industry standard algorithms".